# MarkerClusterGroup not updating data in the supposed way

Tags: javascript, leaflet, leaflet.markercluster, pbiviz

I'm currently developing a visual for power BI using the leaflet library and markerclustergroup as its plugin.

The MarkerClusterGroup works perfectly when no filter is performed on the data used on the dataView.

Here is what I did so far ..

// Remove Layer of clusters when New data is available.
    if (this.centr){

```
      this.clusters.clearLayers();

        }
```

// Here I'm created my Markers :

```
this.centr = L.geoJson(centroids,{
              pointToLayer: function(feature,geometry){
                var marker = new customMarker(geometry,{icon:icon});
                marker.value = Population;
                marker.name = Name;
                return marker;
              }
            });
```

// Here I clear the clusters in case they are not empty for the case of applying filter.

```
          if (this.clusters != undefined){
            this.clusters.clearLayers();
}
```

// Here Creating the clusters

```
                  this.clusters = L.markerClusterGroup({
                  polygonOptions: {
                    fillColor: "Blue",
                    color:"black"
                  },
                  maxClusterRadius:100,
                  singleMarkerMode: true,
                  showCoverageOnHover: true,
                  iconCreateFunction: function(cluster) {
                    // Some Code
                    if (volume == 0){
                      return L.divIcon({html: '<b> Empty !</b>'});
                    }
                    else
                    return L.divIcon({html: '<b>' + volume + '</b>', iconSize: [47,15]});
                  }
                });

          this.clusters.addLayer(this.centr);
          this.map.addLayer(this.clusters);
```

Applying this code, when I filter on some data, I get the new clusters but when I zoom Out or zoom in (to cluster) I get this error :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_leaflet_id' of undefined
    at n (<anonymous>:38:536)
    at e.removeLayer (<anonymous>:40:805)
    at e._hideCoverage (<anonymous>:374:20)
    at e.fire (<anonymous>:38:16896)
    at e._moveEnd (<anonymous>:39:9725)
    at e.<anonymous> (<anonymous>:39:16415)
```

Comment: Would you be able to share a live reproduction example, e.g. using a code snippet, jsfiddle, plunker, etc?

Answer (score 0):

```
if (this.clusters != undefined)
```

Hi,

Try with
`if (this.clusters !== undefined)` with `!==`

Comment: The problem is not there, it enters the If, the problem is in removing the layers from this.map . Because Can't call this.map.removeLayer(this.clusters)